# Finding the longest entries for a given column (nvarchar(100))

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, performance, performance-tuning

I am trying to find the biggest / longest entries of a column which is of type `nvarchar(100)`. I need to understand if I can maybe restrict that column to be only `nvarchar(20)` or something. Is there a way to do so? I know that I can't change the type to `nvarchar(20)` if I have any longer entries.

Comment: should that really be downvoted? I understand that the solution is simple, but for me with no developer background it just didn't came to my mind.

Comment: I downvoted because it didn't show any research effort, a quick google search would've yielded a couple different solutions on the first page. Basic SQL questions are also more suited to SO than DBA.SE, just a heads up.

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve this with this code snippet:

```
SELECT TOP 1 LEN(column), column
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY LEN(column) DESC
```

Just replace column with your column which holds the `nvarchar(100)`

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively,

```
SELECT MAX(LEN(column)) 
FROM table;
```

would work equally as good (if not better as it should eliminate the Sort operator)

Comment: But he won't get the row with the original length. Which means he probably could get a row with trash data (e.g. 'some------------------string') :-)

Comment: Well if there's a value in there greater than `NVARCHAR(20)` he cannot restrict the size, even if it is trash data :-)